# NetSuite Suitelet File Output

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I've been using Suitelets within NetSuite to generate and return PDF documents for a long time. However, for a while now they've been getting returned as **"scriptlet.nl"** instead of **"filename.pdf"**, which is what I used to get. For the life of me I don't understand why. I've used both of the following with the same results:

```
function suiteletA(request, response) {
    var xml = "";
    // processing to generate XML
    response.setContentType("PDF", "output.pdf", "inline");
    var file = nlapiXMLToPDF(xml);
    response.write(file.getValue());
}

function suiteletB(request, response) {
    var xml = "";
    // processing to generate XML
    response.setContentType("PDF", "output.pdf", "inline");
    response.renderPDF(xml);
}
```

I've looked back through previous code and don't see anything obvious that could explain it. Am I missing something here at all? I don' know if it makes a difference, but I typically work within Chrome, so I can't help but to wonder if that has something to do with it, too, like if something was changed within Chrome to cause a change in results.

**-- EDIT --**

Here's a screen shot of the response headers...

[image]

Comment: that's weird. It looks correct. What do you see in terms of disposition and content type in Chrome's inspector?

Comment: I honestly don't know what you're asking me to look at. I'm assuming you want something from the Dev Tools of the browser, but not sure what specifically.

Comment: On the page where you trigger the creation of the pdf start Chrome and show the dev tools. Click Preserve Log on the network tab. Invoke the process that creates the PDF. The network tab will show the response and you should have headers for disposition and content type there. roughly [this](https://blog.versionone.com/spy-on-browser-http-requests/) though it's a few years old.

Comment: I added a screen shot to the post to help. The content type is there, and what it is expected to be, but I don't see a disposition header.

Comment: You are missing the content-disposition header.  I have mostly done this with the first form: `response.write(file.getValue());` Is there any chance you are returning early from the call?

Comment: If you are not returning early then you should open a ticket with Netsuite.

Comment: If I have "return" commands, they're never until after writing the file to the output. But while tinkering with other PDF output, in some sense I can't help but wonder now if the outcome is based on GET versus POST calls. I'll have to do some testing, but in some cases there's too much information to pass in as URL parameters for a GET call to be viable.

Comment: I discovered that if you use method "A", you get the content-disposition header, but not if you use method "B".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what the deal is.

It seems to be that if the script writing a PDF back to the browser is doing so as an HTTP GET, you can download the file with the actual PDF name and all, but if the script is running as an HTTP POST, you get the results I'm reporting. At least, that's what's happening when using Chrome. Similarly, in Firefox, you don't get the "scriptlet.nl", but seemingly "document.pdf" as a downloadable file.

So, something definitely seems goofy with Chrome when it comes to NetSuite and PDF output. It's also badly rendering the BFO XML-based PDF documents, causing entire lines of characters to render on top of each other.You can refresh the document so it doesn't look crazy, but it still prints the letters on top of each other, even they longer appear that way on the screen.